# Resaltar fechas vencidas en input date

Tags: html, css3, datepicker

Es posible de una lista de fechas, resaltar aquellas que estén vencidas?

Para que sea más fácil ubicarlas.

Por ejemplo

```
2016-10-29
2016-10-01
2016-10-29
2016-10-29
2016-10-29
2016-10-29
```

Que quede resaltada en rojo la fecha 2016-10-01

Comment: ¿Con qué finalidad? ¿Puedes agregar un pedazo del código donde te gustaría implementar esto? No soy muy conocedor de tecnología web pero yo lo haría con js para hacerlo más dinámico.

Comment: Se llama negrita (bold) `<b>fecha</b>`.

Comment: Revisa esta [pregunta y respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6857025/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer básicamente es comparar la fecha para determinar si es menor a la actual y en caso de ser así aplicar una clase css con la cual personalizas los estilos.

```
function esMenorQueFecha(fecha1) {
  return fecha1 < new Date();
}

var fechaComoString = '2016-10-01';
var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
var newContent = document.createTextNode(date);
if(esMenorQueFecha(new Date(fechaComoString))) {
 newContent.className = 'menor';
}
newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
```

css

```
.menor {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respusta. Si tuviera el formulario por ejemplo esta parte: <td><input type=date name="fecha1" id="fecha1"></td> cómo podría usar ese js?